# show progress bar when uploadingan image to my server

Tags: iphone, progress-bar, nsurlconnection

my app upload an image to my server.
i want to show this event by a progress bar.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

i use this above methods to see the prgressing in console.
but how i do that in nib file using 'progress bar'?

Comment: I know this is a very old quesiton, but were you ever able to do this? Any idea how I could use this with the latest Facebook SDK 3.1? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

If you use a UIProgressView you can set the progress in the connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite: method like this:

```
float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];
progressView.progress = progress/total;
```

Comment: Why instantiate an NSNumber when you can just cast values for free?

Comment: progressView.progress = (float)totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite